# How to return true to a function above

Tags: json, angularjs, firebase

I am using firebase onauth() method but need to return a value of the function to the one above thats calling it. How can i return true to a function above as shown in this code:

```
    signedIn: function(){

        ref.onAuth(function(authData) {
          if (authData) {
            console.log("Authenticated with uid:", authData.uid);
            return true
          } else {
            console.log("Client unauthenticated.")
          }
        });
    }
```

Comment: If onAuth is asynchronous (and I assume it is), you can't... you'll have to pass a callback to signedIn, or use a promise (see $q).

Comment: Return values that are not immediately ready are usually implemented by `Promise` objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a promise:

```
function signedIn(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    ref.onAuth(function(authData) {
      if (authData) {
        console.log("Authenticated with uid:", authData.uid);
        deferred.resolve();
        return true
      } else {
        console.log("Client unauthenticated.")
        deferred.reject();
      }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}

signedIn().then(function () {
    alert('Authenfication successful!');
});
```